# What should I do if I want to know whether an object is in an NSArray or not by it's address?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5

[NSArray containsObject] use isEqual. isEqual default to the address.

Say I want to know if [NSArray containsObject] based on reference? So I want to know whether that actual object, rather than an object eQual to it, is in the array.

I want to use it for to compare core data objects. Core data objects may be deleted and dereferenced and I wonder what happen to all array that contain elements that reference it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> isEqual default to the address

And in that case, is there a problem?

It sounds like you want to store objects where `isEqual` does *not* use the address, but still use the address for this check, right?

There's no `-[containsObjectIdenticalTo:]`, but there is an `-[indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:]`; if that returns anything but NSNotFound, it's contained.

```
if ([anArray indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:anObject] != NSNotFound) {
}
```

As [the NSArray reference docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html) make clear:

> Objects are considered identical if their object addresses are the same.

There's a whole family of `Identical` methods on `NSArray` and other collections, that are there exactly for this purpose.